# Adding CSS double border to <svg> element without style attribute

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to add double border style to the `<svg>` element without using the style attribute or external stylesheet or using inline `<style>` element within the `<svg>`. After going thru the `<svg>` MDN documentation, I found a way to add border around the `<svg>` as shown below but I was able to only draw a solid border instead of double.

**Actual Output:**

```html
<svg width="250" height="100">
  <rect x="1.5" y="1.5" width="247" height="97" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" fill="none"/>
  <text x="45" y="50" id="xc">Double Border Example</text>  
</svg>
```

**Expected Output:**

This solution using the `style` attribute on the `<svg>` element with outline css property.

```html
<svg width="250" height="100" style="outline: 3px double red;">
  <text x="45" y="50" id="xc">Double Border Example</text>  
</svg>
```

Is there a way to draw double border using the `<rect>` solution?

Comment: perhaps with two rectangles, one slightly bigger than the other, stacked ontop of each other?

Comment: @Apodemus, thank you for the suggestion as I was able to achieve it using 2 rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the double border style on the `<svg>` using 2 `<rect>` elements as shown below,

```html
<svg width="250" height="100">
  <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="249" height="99" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="1" fill="none"/>
  <rect x="2.5" y="2.5" width="245" height="95" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="1" fill="none"/>
  <text x="45" y="50" id="xc">Double Border Example</text>  
</svg>
```